# payara-micro start with java main method

Tags: java, payara

I have a problem with the payara micro embeeded. I want to start my java ee application with the payara micro in eclipse. But it doesn't work.

I created a simple java ee project with three classes.

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}


@Path("ping")
public class PingResource {

    @GET
    public String ping() {
        return "Enjoy Java EE 8!";
    }

}
```

And finally the "main" class of my code.

```
public class Startup {
    public static void main(String... args) throws BootstrapException {
        PayaraMicro.getInstance() //
                .setHttpAutoBind(true) //
                .bootStrap();
    }
}
```

The pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lube</groupId>
    <artifactId>payaramicro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        
        <payara.version>5.194</payara.version>
        
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-micro</artifactId>
            <version>${payara.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>payaramicro</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>com.lube.Mona</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After the startup i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" fish.payara.micro.BootstrapException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.bootStrap(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1076)
    at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.bootStrap(PayaraMicro.java:143)
    at com.lube.Startup.main(Startup.java:10)
Caused by: javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:99)
    at javax.json.Json.createWriterFactory(Json.java:253)
    at fish.payara.appserver.micro.services.data.InstanceDescriptorImpl.toJsonString(InstanceDescriptorImpl.java:301)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.dumpFinalStatus(PayaraMicroImpl.java:2596)
    at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.bootStrap(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1068)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:96)
    ... 6 more
```

The goal of my project is to start the application easily with eclipse ( to debug and so on )

I also tried to start the application with the command "mvn compile exec:exec" which is described on the payara micro github page (https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/blob/master/payara-micro/simplest-bootstrap/pom.xml)

With the command the payara started up successfully, but the page "resources/ping" is unavailable.

Is it possible to have the java ee code and the payara embeeded main method in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Deployment Example](https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/tree/master/payara-micro/deployment-example) was what you meant to do.

The key step would be to set the deployment directory to be the Maven target directory:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws BootstrapException {
        PayaraMicro.getInstance()
                .setDeploymentDir(new File("my_project_path/target"))
                .setHttpAutoBind(true)
                .bootStrap();
    }
```

The specifics of deploying when bootstrapping can be found in the manual: https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-micro/deploying/deploy-program-bootstrap.html

If you want to use the [Payara Micro Maven Plugin](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/ecosystem/maven-plugin.html), you should give a look to [this example](https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/tree/master/payara-micro/demystifying-microservices-example).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i tried it again. It seems that it work with the command link "mvn compile exec:exce" but it doesn't work with eclipse (Right Click -> Run As -> Java Application). I get following exception: "Exception in thread "main" fish.payara.micro.BootstrapException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found"

I don't find a good solution to develop directly on the payara micro. The payara tools (eclipse) does only work with the full payara server. Is there any alternative?

Comment: The alternative is to use NetBeans, an IDE that works very well with Maven. But Eclipse works fine with Maven, you just need to learn how to configure it to run Maven projects. If you can't find how, post a question about this on StackOverflow.